# when i used creatorId:getters.user.id it tell me id undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Here is all the data that I want to send to the firebase, all work but the first one doesn't work, the one called creatorId:

```
   ReceveMeetup ({commit ,getters } ,payload) {
     const meetup = {
    title:payload.title,
    location:payload.location,
    date:payload.date,
    time:payload.time,
    url:payload.url,
    content:payload.content,
```

Here I am trying to make the post take the same id of the writer that saved in the database and couldn't create that in firebase to bring it back after

```
        creatorId:getters.user.id ,



      }
      // send the data to  firebase 
      firebase.database().ref('meetups').push(meetup).then(
        (data) => {
          const key = data.key
          commit('ReceveMeetup',{
            ...meetup,
            id:key,

          })   })
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error) ; } )
    }, 

     getters: {
    loadedMeetups (state) {
      return state.loadedMeetups.sort((meetupA ,meetupB)=> {
          return meetupA.date ===meetupB.date
      })
    },
    featureMeetups (state , getters){
      return getters.loadedMeetups.slice(0,5)
    },
    loadedMeetup (state) {
      return (meetupId) => {
        return state.loadedMeetups.find((meetup)=> {
          return meetup.id === meetupId
        })} 
    },
    user (state) {return state.user  },
    loading (state) {return state.loading},
    error (state) {return state.error},
  }
});
```

Comment: What happens when you debug it?  What happens when you log `getters.user.id` to the console?

Comment: it says     Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains undefined in property 'meetups.creatorId'

Comment: It seems your `user.id` is not defined and we are not shown the right code to know what's wrong.  You could try posting all of your code to [codesandbox.io](https://www.codesandbox.io)